# Will URL-Rewriting with IIS7 require code change?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've got an ASP.NET application up and running on a server. I'd like to implement URL Rewriting, which will involve query strings. I've downloaded IIS Manager and am remotely connecting to the host server (running IIS 7). If I enable URL Rewriting and add all the relevant rules, will my source code require any changes? Or is it simply a case of configuring the settings in IIS Manager and letting it do all the work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you are fearing will break?

Comment: It's just the general working of the search function. For example, 
when the user searches, the url becomes `www.mysite.com/search.aspx?fName=John&sName=Smith`
The server side code simply reads the query string and enters it into the search function using `Request.QueryString["fNAme"]`
After the rewrite, I'm hoping it will be `www.mysite.com/John/Smith`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will. You can rewrite your rules in such a way that you don't have to change the GET variables (querystring) related code however all your link generation code needs to be rewritten to utilize your pretty urls.

Comment: Is it possible use redirection to redirect the old 'dirty' generated links to make them use the pretty urls?